# Redis Synchronous replication failure scenarios

Tags: redis

In redis cluster specification here https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial it mentions

```
    however note that Redis Cluster does not implement strong consistency even when synchronous replication is used: 
it is always possible under more complex failure scenarios that a slave that was not able to receive the write is elected as master.
```

If I issue WAIT command with

```
WAIT 0 <No.Of Salves>
```

then I am forcing at the expense of availability to write data in all the slaves. Could you explain me in this scenario how can synchronous replication doesn't meet consistency requirements as mentioned above
 https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Specifically I want to understand the complex failure scenarios that a slave that was not able to receive the write is elected as master when I issue `WAIT 0 <No.OfSlaves>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Master node might fail before WAIT returns, i.e. write operations haven't been replicated to all slaves. In this case, some slaves have already synced these write operations, while other haven't. When Redis Cluster tries to elect a new master, it might elect a slave, which haven't been fully synced, and the write is lost forever.

Even if the write operations have been fully synced to all slaves, and one of these slave has been elected as the new master, these write operations might be lost. For example, if the new master is restarted before it dumps these write operations to disk. If this new master comes back before a new election triggered, these write operations have been lost.

Comment: what if all the replicas also use `appendfsync always` ? Then the writes cannot get lost.

Comment: First of all, always syncing write to disk largely hurts Redis performance. The replication is async, so even if writes are persisted on replicas, they still might be lost, i.e. master is down before replicas receive these writes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `WAIT 0 <no of slave>` in the client call and `appendfsync always` in the redis.conf file of all the slaves.

This should ensure 2 things:

1. All the slaves/replicas received the write command.
2. All the slaves acknowledge only when they write it to their respective
   appendonly.aof file.

Of course, you are losing on throughput here. But then the cluster could perform as an HA setup, rather than for throughput.

At the end of the day, you have to measure the performance degradation to decide.