# Write Loss in Synchronous write in Redis Cluser

Tags: redis, distributed-computing, distributed-system, redis-cluster

There is a Paragraph in https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial which says:

> Redis Cluster has support for synchronous writes when absolutely needed, implemented via the WAIT command, this makes losing writes a lot less likely, however note that Redis Cluster does not implement strong consistency even when synchronous replication is used: it is always possible under more complex failure scenarios that a slave that was not able to receive the write is elected as master.

What I understand, Synchronous write is supposed to be working as follows:
1. Client Z sends data D to B
2. B sends data D to B1, B2 and B3
3. B waits for ack from B1, B2 and B3
4. B returns response success to Z

Where Z is a client, B is Master node of shard, B1, B2 and B3 are replicas of B.

**My question is even in complex scenarios, how can it fails in Synchronous write as Synchronous write?**

Comment: Check the answer at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349100/redis-synchronous-replication-failure-scenarios